# Backspace key issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an text box and applied Allow Alphabets With Space only using jquery. Its working in chrome But in firefox the backspace key is not working.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" id="id1">

$(function(){
$('#id1').keypress(function (event) {
      if ((event.which >= 65 && event.which < 91) || (event.which > 96 && event.which < 123) || event.which === 32 || event.which===0) {
          return true;
      }
        else {
          event.preventDefault();
      }
 })});
```

Here it is [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B1zBQlAoklq1gPlTeokw?p=preview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a difference in how the browsers handle the backspace character. In Chrome, backspace never makes it to the keypress event handler, but in Firefox it does.

If you add `|| event.which === 8` to your conditional, you'll allow backspace and return true, which will get it working in Firefox.

**EDIT**: Arrow Up, Down,Left, Right and Tab also doesn't work in firefox.

```
var ignoredKeys = [8, 9, 37, 38, 39, 40];

if (ignoredKeys.indexOf(event.which) >=0 || (event.which >= 65 && event.which < 91) || (event.which > 96 && event.which < 123) || event.which === 32 || event.which===0) {
    return true;
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all [major] browsers:

```
$('#id1').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 8) {
        // ...
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

Note the use of `keydown` instead of `keypress`, which is essential for it to work.