# Backspace key is not working in firefox , but works in chrome/opera

Tags: javascript, validation, google-chrome, firefox

I have a autocomplete textbox which must support backspace.This piece of code is working fine in chrome and opera , but in firefox backspace is not working.
I tried this answer

[Backspace key issue in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580493/backspace-key-issue-in-firefox)

but it is not working. here is mycode :

```
$("#approverOne").keypress(function (e) {
    var theEvent = e || window.event || e.charCode;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    if(key===8){return;}
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
   }

e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

despite of best efforts and numerous trials , still I am not sure how to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

on pressing backspace console shows above image.

Comment: `console.log(key)` - and see what key value actually is for backspace

Comment: the syntax error is not present in your code when in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/vLc0mu6a/) - have you posted different code to the code you actually use? If you click on one of those errors you should see a stack trace, can you see where in your code the error is triggered?

Comment: no code is same !!! i cross checked and then posted it, i also added console.log(key) ,after execution i got this , i am literally trying it for hours

Comment: what happens for you in the fiddle I linked to? Also, what version of firefox in what operating system?

Comment: In fiddle it is working fine . firefox version is 50.0.1

Comment: interesting that you are getting a warning about `08` - yet your code doesn't have `08` it has `8`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: if you use the developer tools inspector and click on the little `ev` next to the input tag with id=approverOne (in your code, not the fiddle) how many keypress events are attached? more than 2?

Comment: jquery 1.9.1-min.js

Comment: `firefox version is 50.0.1` - which operating system? windows, linux, whatever apples use?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: given the fiddle, with exactly your code as posted here, works, I can only assume the problem stems from code you haven't posted - the fact that you get the `08` warning makes me suspect there's another piece of code that is also listening for keydown/up/press events which screws the pooch. developer tools inspector *may* help to see what events are attached to the input in question

Comment: check the number of events attached to the input element : "approverOne"

Comment: you seem to have a keyup and a keydown event on that input - either one of them could be the culprit - are you loading any other significant libraries, jQuery or otherwise

Comment: yes there are numerous jquery files :  jquery-1.9.1.min.js jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js   jquery.slimscroll.min.js   . Atleast 20 files which are .js/.css type