# Firefox : There is no such field called inputType in keydown event object

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, cross-browser

I have an `input` event and a `keydown` event bound to a textbox in angular. In keydown event function I'm recieving an `input` object as the object representing the event in firefox. At the same time, I'm receiving an `InputEvent` object for the same event  in chrome. I'm using the `inputType` field in the `InputEvent` object in chrome to identify if it is `insertText`, `deleteContentBackward`  or `deleteContentForward` event as given below.

```
switch(event.inputType) {
   case 'insertText':
     //do something
   break;
   case 'deleteContentBackward':
     //do something
   break;
   case 'deleteContentForward':
     //do something
   break;
}
```

The problem is there is no such field called `inputType` in the event object generated by firefox.

Event object in Chrome (71.0.3578.98)

```
InputEvent {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelBubble: false,
        cancelable: false,
        composed: true,
        currentTarget: null,
        data: null,
        dataTransfer: null,
        defaultPrevented: true,
        detail: 0,
        eventPhase: 0,
        **inputType: "deleteContentBackward"**,
        isComposing: false,
        isTrusted: true,
        path: (15) [input#search-input.form-control.custom-input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched, div.col-md-9.search-input-container, div.col-12.no-padding.search.custom-search-box, div.row.input-group.col-lg-6.col-md-7.col-sm-9.col-xs-12, div.search-section.col-12, app-search-header, div.container, section#homeBanner.intro, app-header, app-root, div.wrapper, body.is-search-open, html.no-js, document, Window],
        returnValue: false,
        sourceCapabilities: null,
        srcElement: input#search-input.form-control.custom-input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched,
        target: input#search-input.form-control.custom-input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched,
        timeStamp: 2484875.1999999997,
        type: "input",
        view: null,
        which: 0
    }
```

Given below is the same event object in firefox (65.0b7)

```
input{
        bubbles: true,
        ​cancelBubble: false,
        ​cancelable: false,
        ​composed: true,
        ​currentTarget: null,
        ​defaultPrevented: false,
        ​detail: 0,
        ​eventPhase: 0,
        ​explicitOriginalTarget: <input id="search-input" class="form-control custom-inpu…lid ng-dirty ng-touched" _ngcontent-c10="" type="text" ng-reflect-model="a" placeholder="What are you looking for ?">,
        ​isComposing: false,
        ​isTrusted: true,
        ​layerX: 0,
        ​layerY: 0,
        ​originalTarget: <input id="search-input" class="form-control custom-inpu…lid ng-dirty ng-touched" _ngcontent-c10="" type="text" ng-reflect-model="a" placeholder="What are you looking for ?">,
        ​pageX: 0,
        ​pageY: 0,
        ​rangeOffset: 0,
        ​rangeParent: null,
        ​returnValue: true,
        ​srcElement: <input id="search-input" class="form-control custom-inpu…lid ng-dirty ng-touched" _ngcontent-c10="" type="text" ng-reflect-model="a" placeholder="What are you looking for ?">​
        target: <input id="search-input" class="form-control custom-inpu…lid ng-dirty ng-touched" _ngcontent-c10="" type="text" ng-reflect-model="a" placeholder="What are you looking for ?">,
        ​timeStamp: 283997,
        **​type: "input"**, // For insert and delete events this field won't change
        ​view: null,
        ​which: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem in [this way, in a jquery environment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580493/backspace-key-issue-in-firefox)

On Angular, I solved the problem this way.

```
isBackSpace = false;

onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent){
  this.isBackSpace = event.which === 8;
  /// rest of the method
}

onSearchChange(event){
  if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentForward' || event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward' || this.IsBackSpace) {
    // delete event handling code.
  } else {
    // insert event handling code.
  }
  this.isBackSpace = false;
}
```